# Impulse a Nape body in direction to a specific position

Tags: actionscript-3, physics, nape

I have a sleep body I want to apply an impulse in direction to a specific x/y position, let's say `x:200, y:300`.

But when this impulse is applied the body moves in direction to the x/y but not to the exactly position, it has a difference range around 30-50 on both x/y. Gravity is `0,0`.

```
var impulse:Vec2 = Vec2.weak(200, 300);
impulse.length = 1000;
napeBody.applyImpulse(impulse);
```

Comment: Seems like `impulse` is relative to `napeBody` and not to global "stage"

Answer (score 5):

Done it.
In case someone need it, you just need to set x/y on the impulse according to your body position:

```
var dx:Number = _destX - napeBody.position.x;
var dy:Number = _destY - napeBody.position.y;

var impulse:Vec2 = Vec2.weak(dx, dy);
impulse.length = 1000;
napeBody.applyImpulse(impulse);
```